# How to add attributes to a Xelement

Tags: c#, xml

This is the code where i am inserting a XElement

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Database.xml");
XElement root = new XElement("SCENE" , "SCENE_" + strSceneName);
var scenePath = doc.XPathSelectElement("//DATABASE");
scenePath.Add(root);
doc.Save("Database.xml");
```

The element is inserted like this

```
<SCENE>SCENE_ProjectedScore_Logo</SCENE>
```

this is what is recquired

```
<SCENE SCENE_NAME="SCENE_ProjectedScore_Logo"SCENE>
```

what changes do i need to do in my code to achieve this.

Comment: Do you want to add a single attribute to `SCENE` element? or want multiple attributes to it?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Multiple attributes under the SCENE

Comment: If there are multiple attributes you want under `SCENE`, then better to use `SetAttributeValue` method. I already mentioned reason to use this method in my answer please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace

```
XElement root = new XElement("SCENE" , "SCENE_" + strSceneName);
```

with

```
XElement root = new XElement("SCENE" , new XAttribute("SCENE_NAME", "SCENE_" + strSceneName));
```

you should have results you seek.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of passing second parameter as a string to `XElement` `root` , use `SetAttributeValue()` function from XElement class.

Like,

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Database.xml");

XElement root = new XElement("SCENE"); //Update instanciation of XElement
root.SetAttributeValue("SCENE_NAME", $"SCENE_{strSceneName}"); //Use this method to set attribute with value. 
 
var scenePath = doc.XPathSelectElement("//DATABASE");
scenePath.Add(root);
doc.Save("Database.xml");
```

MSDN documentation: [XElement.SetAttributeValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.setattributevalue?view=net-5.0)

---

Benefit of `XElement.SetAttributeValue()` over calling XElement constructor with XAttribute parameter is: [(From MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.setattributevalue?view=net-5.0#remarks)

> This method is designed to make it easy to maintain a list of
> name/value pairs as a set of attributes.